# How do I turn a long pair dataset with repeated appearances into a matrix frequency table

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to change this long dataset that takes all appearances

```
dt <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 
5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7), V1 = c("ABC", "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "GHI", 
"GHI", "JKL", "JKL", "DEF", "ABC", "MNO", "GHI", "GHI", "ABC", 
"DEF", "DEF", "GHI", "MNO", "MNO", "ABC"), V2 = c("DEF", "MNO", 
"MNO", "JKL", "DEF", "ABC", "DEF", "ABC", "ABC", "JKL", "JKL",                                                                                               
"ABC", "DEF", "DEF", "GHI", "MNO", "MNO", "ABC", "JKL", "JKL"
)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

and turn it into a matrix that looks like this.

```
    V2
V1    ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO
ABC   0   3   2   3   2
DEF   3   0   3   1   2
GHI   2   3   0   1   1
JKL   3   1   1   0   2
MNO   2   2   1   2   0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** Compute the levels, levs, and turn each column into a factor with those levels.  Then use table to get the frequencies and symmetrize to get the complete result.

```
levs <- sort(unique(unlist(dt[, -1])))
DF <- as.data.frame(lapply(dt[, -1], factor, levels = levs))
tab <- table(DF)
tab + t(tab)
```

giving:

```
     V2
V1    ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO
  ABC   0   3   2   3   2
  DEF   3   0   3   1   2
  GHI   2   3   0   1   1
  JKL   3   1   1   0   2
  MNO   2   2   1   2   0
```

**2)** or even shorter is to rbind columns 2 and 3 to columns 3 and 2, i.e. swap the two columns, and take the frequencies using table.  Note that dt in the question is a data.table and this uses rbind.data.table .

```
library(data.table)
table(rbind(dt[, 2:3], dt[, 3:2]))
```

giving:

```
     V2
V1    ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO
  ABC   0   3   2   3   2
  DEF   3   0   3   1   2
  GHI   2   3   0   1   1
  JKL   3   1   1   0   2
  MNO   2   2   1   2   0
```

To use rbind.data.frame instead of rbind.data.table the code would have to be adjusted since the former requires identical names.

```
df <- as.data.frame(dt)
table(rbind(df[2:3], replace(df[2:3], TRUE, df[3:2])))
```

Answer (score 2):

An option if you are wanting the actual counts to consider each line of data for a matrix, then you could use this:

```
library(data.table)
library(tibble)

A <- dcast(V1 ~ V2, data=dt, length)
tab <- as.matrix(tibble::column_to_rownames(A, var = "V1"))
```

This gives the following result:

```
    ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO
ABC   0   2   0   2   1
DEF   1   0   1   0   2
GHI   2   2   0   1   1
JKL   1   1   0   0   0
MNO   1   0   0   2   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `igraph` like below

```
library(igraph)
get.adjacency(
    graph_from_data_frame(dt[, -"ID"],
        directed = FALSE
    ),
    sparse = FALSE
)
```

which gives

```
    ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO
ABC   0   3   2   3   2
DEF   3   0   3   1   2
GHI   2   3   0   1   1
JKL   3   1   1   0   2
MNO   2   2   1   2   0
```